# Upgrade from richfaces 3.3 to 4.2 and primefaces from 1.1 to 2.2.1

Tags: jsf-2, jar, richfaces, primefaces, upgrade

I try to upgrade from richfaces 3.3 to 4.2 and primefaces from 1.1 to 2.2.1

I have these jars:

- jsf-api-2.0.3.jar (was 1.2 before)
- jsf-facelets-1.1.9.jar
- jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar (was 1.2 before)
- richfaces-components-api-4.2.0.Final
- richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-api-4.2.0.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar
- myfaces-orchestra-core-1.4.jar
- myfaces-orchestra-core20-1.4.jar
- primefaces-2.2.1.jar
- guava-11.0.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- quartz-1.6.0.jar
- servlet-api.jar (85.287 Bytes) (28.01.2008)
- el-impl-1.0.jar
- el-messages.jar
- facelets-taglib-jsf12-spring-3-0.4.jar

and some Spring 3.1.0 jars

but I get:

```
Error Loading Library: jar:file:/C:/Users/XXX/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/XXX/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/rich.taglib.xml
java.io.IOException: Error parsing [jar:file:/C:/Users/XXX/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/XXX/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/rich.taglib.xml]:
```

when i remove jsf-facelets-1.1.9.jar, i get

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document: jndi:/localhost/XXX/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Unable to find class 'com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler'

<application>
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
    <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

after removing this  tag I get

```
Schwerwiegend: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Orchestra was unable to create an instance of bean with name 'AccessScopeManager'. Ensure that JSF variable resolution uses your dependency injection (DI) framework (eg Spring's DelegatingVariableResolver is in your faces-config.xml file) and the standard Orchestra configuration beans are defined (eg by using <import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring-orchestra-init.xml" />).
```

... I think I need some help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have upgraded to JSF 2 and JSF 2 comes with facelets built in so it is *unlikely* that you want to use the old facelets jar `jsf-facelets-1.1.9.jar` on your classpath.

BalusC (stackoverflow's JSF expert) has this written this excellent guide 
[Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) on how to upgrade, it also covers facelets upgrading.

I also you are using facelets-taglib-**jsf12**-spring-3-0.4.jar

According to the [spring-security-facelets-taglib](http://code.google.com/p/spring-security-facelets-taglib/) you will need to use 
facelets-taglib-jsf20-spring-3

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these reports:

- [API changes report](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/primefaces.html) for the PrimeFaces library:

[image]

- [API changes report](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/richfaces.html) for the RichFaces library:

[image]

Comment: I did…  and? What do they say and what is your conclusion?